# Jquery / Ajax used on PHP page in a for loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I recently learned that when using onclick, for a button, the field name and button id have to each be unique. While thats not a problem, depending on how many rows my script outputs, this could be a lot of waste.

For example, i have a while loop, it does this for each person on my server (minecraft), so it could be 10, it could be 50.

this is the code to create the js objects

```
  $kickbtn .= "    $('#kick_btn$k').click(function(event) { 
    var player_name$k = jQuery('input[name=\"player$k\"]').val()
    jQuery.get('testing.php?action=kick', { player_input: player_name$k} );
    alert('Successfully kicked');
  });\n\n";
```

this is the form data

```
    <form name=\"$pdata[name]\" action=\"\">
      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"player$k\" value=\"$pdata[name]\">
      <input type=\"submit\" id=\"kick_btn$k\" value=\"Kick Player\">
    </form>
  $k++;
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this without creating all this excess code?

The output is nice in the html, and it does work, just hoping theres something a little more dynamic i can do, and not so messy in the code. Below is from the parsed code and works and looks good.

```
$('#kick_btn14').click(function(event) { 

    var player_name14 = jQuery('input[name="player14"]').val()

    jQuery.get('testing.php?action=kick', { player_input: player_name14} );

    alert('Successfully kicked');

  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one delegated event handler is needed, which means attaching it to a parent/container element, unless you want 50+ click handlers in your document which will unnecessarily slow things down:

```
// bind to all elements starting with 'kick_btn' within #container
// (could even be 'body')
$("#container").delegate('[id^="kick_btn"]', "click", function(event) {

    // get the current player number from the id of the clicked button
    var num = this.id.replace("kick_btn", "");
    var player_name = jQuery('input[name="player' + num + '"]').val();
    jQuery.get('testing.php?action=kick', {
        player_input: player_name + num
    });
    alert('Successfully kicked');
});
```

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: while there will be a small decrease in load time from the reduced document size it's worth mentioning that, while totally sensible, this approach might result in an overall increase in load time on the client, proportional to the number of elements in the document. The OP's original approach is not pretty but it requires less processing.

Comment: @tomfumb - I'll tweak the answer, wasn't even thinking about the number of click handlers (thanks for the pointer).

Comment: var num = this.id.replace("kick_btn", ""); i think there is something wrong with that line, num always returns nothing

Comment: Weird, shouldn't be the case. Check out this minimal test: http://jsfiddle.net/yFaAj/2/

Comment: @karim79 thanks - you just introduced me to the delegate function, looks very useful

Comment: @karim79 thanks, i figured it out. bone head mistake on my side, your code works perfect! one question, how can i make it so it doesnt add ?player16=fffizzz to the URL on click?